# Resolve: "Unknown system error -86" error when installing imagemin-pngquant/imagemin-optipng on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp-imagemin, pngquant

Here's the error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /[...]/node_modules/pngquant-bin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! ⚠ spawn Unknown system error -86
npm ERR!   ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
npm ERR!   ℹ compiling from source
npm ERR!   ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng is installed
npm ERR!     at /[...]/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
npm ERR!     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Note: This is a purely native execution (no Rosetta translation).

Looks like there's an issue whenever a package needs to build a component in C.

---

**Update 1.**

I have created issues with the following repositories:

1. [pngquant-bin (imagemin-pngquant)](https://github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/issues/121)
2. [optipng-bin (imagemin-optipng)](https://github.com/imagemin/optipng-bin/issues/117)
3. [mozjpeg (imagemin-mozjpeg)](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-mozjpeg/issues/61)

Comment: Have you tried running it through Rosetta?

Comment: I know it will work in Rosetta. Just seems odd that packages like pngquant installs fine using Homebrew but not via npm.

Comment: It seems to indicate that there isn't really an issue with the package running on Apple Silicon, but the environment.

Comment: If this were anything more complicated I would have "settled" to use Rosetta, but I know C/C++ builds fine on Apple Silicon, so I must be making a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use a supported imagemin package**

The following imagemin packages will install on Apple Silicon:

**PNG:**
[imagemin-oxipng](https://github.com/HackPlan/imagemin-oxipng)
[imagemin-zopfli](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-zopfli)

**Gifs:**
[imagemin-gifsicle](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle)

**JPEG:**
[imagemin-jpegtran](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran)

**2. Use Rosetta 2**

[Link to official install instructions from Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861)

Comment: How do you know which packages are supported on Apple silicon?